# CVS recursive commit - “there is no version here; do `cvs checkout' first”

Tags: cvs

we have a hierachically organized maven project in our CVS and we are using jenkins to increase maven versions in the project and its child modules.

We are running into the following error.

```
[cvs, commit, -m, Jenkins: 1.2-SNAPSHOT -> 1.3-SNAPSHOT] returned 1 in working directory /app/builds/jenkins/jenkinsdevhead/jobs/Test_Groovy_CreateNewBranch_Hierarch/workspace/maven-test-project-hierarch
Error output:
cvs commit: Examining .
cvs commit: Examining .settings
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/.settings
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/.settings
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java/de
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java/de/dwpbank
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java/de/dwpbank/devinf
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java/de/dwpbank/devinf/build
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/src/main/java/de/dwpbank/devinf/build/test
cvs commit: Examining maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/target
cvs commit: in directory `maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/target':
cvs [commit aborted]: there is no version here; do `cvs checkout' first
```

.cvsignore  in maven-test-project-module1-hierarch is as follows

```
.settings
.project
target/
target
```

Why isn't `maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/target` ignored by the commit?

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the content of the maven-test-project-module1-hierarch/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch/CVS/Entries file?

Comment: `/.classpath/1.1/Mon Apr 27 11:05:07 2015//
    /.project/1.1/Mon Apr 27 11:05:07 2015//
    /pom.xml/1.1/Mon Apr 27 11:05:07 2015//
    D/.settings////
    D/maven-test-project-module1-submodule1-hierarch////
    D/maven-test-project-module1-submodule2-hierarch////`